# sed cut grep linux command output

Tags: awk, sed, split, grep, cut

i have a string, i want to cut all occurrences from matching until first comma: example

`[{"value":1,"btata":"15","Id":"17","","url":"","time":"222"{"value":1,"secId":"16","Id":"19","time":"20218 22status":""}`

I want to get Id:17 Id:19

I have been able to get Id using `sed -e 's/Id/_/g' -e 's/[^_]//g' -e 's/_/Id /g'` but couldn't match until comma.

Comment: Since this is JSON, try `jq` instead: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `sed` but it requires two expressions. Essentially you need to remove all `'"'` characters and then split the input on `','` by replacing them with `'\n'`. The second expression simply locates the lines beginning with `Id`, e.g.

```
sed 's/"//g;s/,/\n/g' | sed -n /^Id/p
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo '[{value:1,btata:15,Id:17,,url:,time:222{value:1,secId:16,Id:19,time:20218 22status:}' | 
sed 's/"//g;s/,/\n/g' | sed -n /^Id/p
Id:17
Id:19
```

(**note:** this all comes with the caveat that you should not process json with shell commands. Using a json validating tool like `jq` is recommended -- though this doesn't appear to be valid json either)